# how to match the text in sqlite query while fetching data in iphone application

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am fetching data from sqlite table using the where clause in which it takes the ContentTag entered and checks in data base problem is that if in data base TagText is Office then it works if the Tag Office,Developer then it does not fetch any record i want that if user pass Office then it should also show record and if it enters Developer then it also show record.

This is the my query

```
select = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * 
FROM ContentMaster LEFT JOIN  Category  ON  ContentMaster.CategoryID= Category.CategoryID 
where ContentMaster.ContentTitle='%@' OR ContentMaster.ContentTagText='%@' ",appDelegate.tagInput,appDelegate.tagInput];
```

I want that if ContentTagText i pass is Office then it should also work and if it is Developer then it should also work.

Comment: Your problem is not so clear.

Comment: try || sign instead of "OR".

Comment: @SmartWork no. This is SQL. You use `OR`, not `||`.

Comment: @AijazAli: specify clearly..or write example output for your input

Comment: @preetam i want the way sunny has posted but i have asked him quetion please see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use command like this,

## sqlite_master

```
id       name             place
==================================
1       office,developer rajkot


SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name like '%Office%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name like '%Developer%'
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name like '%Office,Developer%'
```

Above all gives same output

it will give the records which contains name like Office,Developer and Office,Developer

Comment: if Name is Office,Developer then it will show result or not

Comment: defenitly it'l show..

Comment: but my value input is in appDelegate.TagInput how i will use that with like

Comment: can you please help me out

Comment: @AijazAli: like `SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name like '%%appDel.tagInput%%'` in objective C you have to use `%%` to specify escabe of `%`

Comment: try like this ,[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT * FROM sqlite_master WHERE name like '%%@%'",appDel.tagInput]

Comment: this works now but like your name in data base it is office,developer but in appDelegate.input it is office then it does not show any record

Comment: it'l show the records i tested those quries my self.